# Ubuntu:: XAMMP: Error message: End of script output before headers: CGI with c++

Tags: xampp, cgi

I am getting some issues while making small website for our internal project.

I have created hello.cpp program and convert to hello.cgi by cmd 
g++ -o hello.cgi hello.cpp -lcgicc

its working fine with - localhost/cgi-bin/hello.cgi

I have created another program test_cgi.cpp and convert it to test_cgi.cgi which will process my http request but server giving error see below image

localhost/cgi-bin/test_cgi.cgi?first_name=abcd&last_name=efg

[image]

can you suggest me what could be the issue??..is there configuration issue.??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Comment: i have gone through process. thanks